# table rate problem

Tags: shipping, magento-1, table-rates

I have a problem with the table rates showing the right price.

I used this

```
Land,Provincie,Postcode,"Subtotaal bestelling (en hierboven)",Verzendkosten
NLD,*,*,0,3,95
BEL,*,*,0,4,95
DEU,*,*,0,7,95
```

When I select the NLD country in the checkout I get the right price 3,95. But when I select the other ones I get strange prices like  BEl 4,02 or Deu 6,02

Comment: Do you have any discount rules that might affect the shipping price

Answer (score 1):

You are using comma's witouth enclosure in a comma seperated csv. This can't be right. Use "3,95".

Comment: or probably `3.95`

Comment: You are right dear sir :)

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate one column with the other by `''` or `""`quotation mark.
And comma in default settings is dot `.`

As mentioned by @Toon Van Dooren and @fschmengler

```
Land,Provincie,Postcode,"Subtotaal bestelling (en hierboven)",Verzendkosten
NLD,*,*,0,'3.95'
BEL,*,*,0,'4.95'
DEU,*,*,0,'7.95'
```